# What is the most portable way to skip arguments for shell scripts?

Tags: shell-script, portability

For portable wrapper scripts intended to run on UNIX systems (*not necessarily Linux*), should the `shift` command be preferred over array syntax?

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exec command ${1+"$@"}
```

Compared with:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
shift
exec command "$@"
```

Comment: These two are hardly equivalent. What makes you think `${1+"$@"}` skips anything?

Comment: The purpose of `${1+"$@"}` is to produce an empty expansion if there are no arguments; `${1+...}` means "if parmeter `$1` is set, then expand `...`.   This idiom is needed in some buggy old shells. According to POSIX, the `"$@"` syntax alone expands to nothing when there are  no arguments. Some shell once upon a time had a bug that `"$@"` expanded to a single empty argument when there were no positional parameters, or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

`exec command ${1+"$@"}` isn't the same as `shift; exec command "$@"`. The latter removes the first argument, the first one doesn't.

What the `${1+"$@"}` does, is to only apply the expansion of `"$@"` if `$1` is set. It doesn't make a difference in POSIX-compatible shells, as `"$@"` is supposed to expand to nothing if no positional parameter is set (and if any are set, then `$1` has to be, the list  can't have "holes"), but as far as I understand, the guard may be needed in some older shells.

On the other hand, in ksh/zsh/Bash, `"${@:2}"` would give the positional parameters starting at `$2`, so, similarly to first shifting off the first one except of course not actually modifying the list.